# setting up controller for test

Tags: rubymotion, specifications

i'm trying to write a functional test for my controller in rubymotion using bacon.

in my controller i have some code that populates some data:

```
def viewWillAppear(animated)
  song_text.text = chant.song_text
  ...
end
```

i am setting the `chant` variable when i push that controller to the navigation-controller.

this works fine in the app, but when i try to do that in a before-block of the spec it does not work, because `viewWillAppear` gets called before the block and it fails with a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'song_text' for nil:NilClass`.

is there some way to handle this situation? is there some other way to populate the data or use a different method than `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: Sounds like a bacon or RubyMotion bug. The before block should be called before the controller is displayed.

Comment: this is the spec, if you wanna have a look: https://github.com/phoet/chant/blob/master/spec/controllers/chant_controller_spec.rb

Comment: Like BSB states in his answer you should make sure you call `super` [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW16) states - `If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation.`

Comment: i found the problem. i was loading a nib and setting the owner to the controller under test in `loadView`. this performs all initialization steps directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RubyMotion support answered my support ticket indicating, that this is the expected behavior of controllers in bacon.

I worked around the whole thing by stubbing my class under test in the bacon spec like so:

```
# spec/chant_controller_spec.rb
class ChantControllerStub < ChantController
  def chant
    @chant ||= create_chant
  end
end

describe "ChantController" do
  tests ChantControllerStub

  it "displays a chant" do
    view('verse').should.not == nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I've experience a similar issue that was solved by calling the `super` method in the `viewWillAppear` method